# Android background transitioning

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, transition

I want the same background image throughout my whole Android app. If I use multiple activities, all with the same background, will the transition between activity A and B in the *final, usable version* be so quick and smooth that it seems like the background was unchanged the whole time, and that only the buttons switched?

If not, do I need to solve this with fragments, using only one activity? How will I do that with the activity XML file, make several copies of it and just place different fragments in each one?

Comment: You can always set a theme for your application. In the styles.xml, you can extend your application theme and set a background drawable. If you want to support multiple devices, fragments is the way to go. But you will have to play around with using activity vs fragments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `window:background` style property to set the background for the entire application.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/app_background</item>
</style>
```

In addition you can disable Activity animation using:

```
<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
```

or

```
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```